# How to show that the points $(0, 0)$ and $(\sqrt{2 \pi},−\sqrt{2 \pi})$ on the curve $e^{x + y} = \cos(xy)$ have a common tangent?

Tags: calculus

Show that the points $(0, 0)$ and $(\sqrt{2 \pi},−\sqrt{2 \pi})$ on the curve $e^{x + y} = \cos(xy)$ have a common tangent.

How do I solve this question? First, I differenciated the curve and I got $e^{x+y} = -\sin(xy) \left ( \frac{dy}{dx} x + y \right )$ but then i don't know how to approach after that.

Comment: The mistake that you made was the you just differentiated the right-hand-side of the equation. You need to differentiate $e^{x+y}$ too, and then solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Try looking at the [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28x%2By%29%3Dcos%28x%2By%29). It is as if only made up of parallel lines

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating equation:
$$e^{x + y} = \cos(xy)$$

We obtain:
$$(dx+dy)e^{x + y}=-(ydx+xdy)\sin(xy)$$

Thus
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= -\frac{e^{x + y} + y\sin(xy)}
          {e^{x + y} + x\sin(xy)}\tag{1}$$

Substituting $(x,y)=(0,0)$ or $(x,y)=(\sqrt{2\pi},-\sqrt{2\pi})$ in (1) leads to the same values for $dy/dx$.

Answer (score -2):

If they have a common tangent, then not only is their slope the same at those two points, but it's the same as the actual slope between the two points.  So plug in those numbers and see what slopes you get.

In order to plug in the numbers, however, you'll want to solve for $dy/dx$ first.  That shouldn't be too hard; just pretend that it's a single thing and it solves easily.